# JavaScript Documentation of Custom Object

Tags: javascript, object, documentation, visual-studio-code

This is a purely `documentation` related question, regarding `JavaScript`.
I want to create an `Object`, and some of its fields are going to be other `Objects`, and state that in the documentation. (I'm using Visual Studio Code).

Here is a simple example declaration of an object.

```
/**
 * @type {Object.<string, number>}
 */
var User = {
    name,
    id
};
```

Which in Documentation should appear like this:

```
var User = {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}
```

This is a more advanced example. Some of the objects fields are actually User Objects

```
/**
 * @type {Object.<string, User>}
 */
var Message = {
    text,
    from
};
```

This is how it should appear in the documentation:

```
var Message = {
    text: string;
    from: {
        name: string;
        id: number;
    };
}
```

This would also be acceptable:

```
var Message = {
    text: string;
    from: User;
}
```

But `Visual Studio Code` shows:

```
var Message = {
    text: string;
    from: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just needed to use `@typedef`.

By using `@typedef` you can create a custom type definition, so to create a custom `Object` you just need to do `@typedef {{}}`. And add all the properties inside that. Once the type has been defined, then you can also use it in another `@typedef`.

So the comment below creates two new types.

```
/**
 * @typedef {{ name: string, id: number }} User
 * @typedef {{ text: string, from: User }} Message
 */
```

Now I just need to  add `@type {User}` and `@type {Message}` respectively

```
/** @type {User} */
var User = {
    name,
    id
};

/** @type {Message} */
var Message = {
    text,
    from
};
```